# How to create a rails habtm that deletes/destroys without error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, nameerror

I created a simple example as a sanity check and still can not seem to destroy an item on either side of a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in rails.

Whenever I try to delete an object from either table, I get the dreaded NameError / "uninitialized constant" error message.

To demonstrate, I created a sample rails app with a Boy class and Dog class.  I used the basic scaffold for each and created a linking table called boys_dogs.  I then added a simple before_save routine to create a new 'dog' any time a boy was created and establish a relationship, just to get things setup easily.

dog.rb

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :Boys  
end
```

boy.rb

```
class Boy < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :Dogs  

  def before_save  
    self.Dogs.build( :name => "Rover" )  
  end  

end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20100118034401) do

  create_table "boys", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "boys_dogs", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "boy_id"
    t.integer  "dog_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "dogs", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

I've seen lots of posts here and elsewhere about similar problems, but the solutions are normally using belongs_to and the plural/singular class names being confused.  I don't think that is the case here, but I tried switching the habtm statement to use the singular name just to see if it helped (with no luck).  I seem to be missing something simple here.

The actual error message is:

> NameError in BoysController#destroy
>   uninitialized constant Boy::Dogs

The trace looks like:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing'
>
>   (eval):3:in`destroy_without_callbacks'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:337:in `destroy_without_transactions'
>
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in`send'
>   ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see your destroy callback, but I do see a couple of problems.  First, your associations need to be lowercase.  So dog.rb should be:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :boys  
end
```

and boy.rb should be:

```
class Boy < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dogs  

  def before_save  
    self.dogs.build( :name => "Rover" )  
  end
end
```

Second, I believe you want to use `self.dogs.create` instead of `self.dogs.build` above, since build won't actually save the new dog object.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.  Changing to lower case did the trick.  Note: Using self.dogs.create won't work unless the boy object has already been saved.  But I could probably move that to the after_save.  The self.dogs.build command seems to work as is.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Bradley-

Glad it helped.  And I bet the model save is actually saving all the built associations too, which is something I didn't know before.

I noticed you're new to the site.  It helps me out if you accept my answer, since it was the one that solved your problem.  That way, I get credit for it.

Thanks,

Jaime

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here solved my problem, only to create another one.

Here are my model objects:

```
class Complex < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name "Complexes"
   set_primary_key "ComplexID"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :amenities
end

class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name "Amenities"
   set_primary_key "AmenityID"
end
```

Rails uses the name of the association as the table name when creating the select query.  My application runs on Unix against a legacy MySQL database and my table names are case-sensitive and don't conform to Rails conventions.  Whenever my app actually tried to load the association, I would get an exception that MySQL couldn't find table `amenities`:

```
SELECT * FROM `amenities` 
INNER JOIN `ComplexAmenities` ON `amenities`.AmenityID = `ComplexAmenities`.AmenityID  
WHERE (`ComplexAmenities`.ComplexID = 147 )
```

I searched and searched and could not find a way to tell Rails to use the correct case for the table name.  Out of desperation, I tried passing a `:table_name` option to habtm and it worked.  My new Complex model looks like this:

```
class Complex < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name "Complexes"
   set_primary_key "ComplexID"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :amenities, :table_name => 'Amenities'
end
```

This works under Rails 2.3.5.

This option is *not* mentioned in the Ruby on Rails docs.